# Facebook messenger bot error nonexisting field (messages)

Tags: facebook-page, facebook-messenger, facebook-oauth, facebook-messenger-bot

I am a new member.

I have an error when send message using HTTP Post to "graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/messages?access_token=MY_PAGE_TOKEN"

This is error return:

```
`{"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"EB39Xkxnf6O"}}`
```

Despite error, tester and developer still able to receive message. But the FB viewer might not and they not approve my review submission:
"We did not receive an automated response when we messaged your Page. Bots should respond to all input from the user within 30 seconds so that the experience feels like a continuous conversation. Please ensure that your experience is functional before you resubmit."

The log show same error with FB viewer when server trying to response.

Any help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation explains you are required to submit a {conversation-id} before the messages.

More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/conversation/messages)