# Building a FaceBook Bot: post request leads to 400 error, and nonexisting field (messages) on node type (page)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, axios

Trying to create a Facebook messenger bot. I've been following the [official FB tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start) (step 6), but ran into an issue for when the bot tries to reply to a user-initiated message. My console logs the following error:

```
"Unable to send message: Error: Request failed with status code 400"
```

When I try to make a post request to the correct URL path , I get the following error:

```
"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (Page)"
```

I'm using the Axios module to make my HTTP post request, and am not 100% certain if my request is properly formatted. I also have the correct page access token. However, I believe the issue is that Facebook changed the "messages" parameter for Pages? If I could get any insight, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some pictures of the errors I'm running into:

**- `callSendAPI` handler**

[image]

**- screenshot of graph api error**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code as text in your question and do not post a screenshot of it. This makes it easier for others to copy the code and to reproduce the problem. Also, the link to the image might become invalid after some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051930/facebook-messenger-bot-error-nonexisting-field-messages/53328596#53328596